# Composition or aggregation

Tags: oop, design-patterns, uml, class-diagram

Please take note of my class diagram. It shows an excerpt from a software for the management of movie showings in a cinema and comes from a study book.

[image]

The study book explains that there is a composition between the room and the seat. If a cinema employee deletes a room, the seats must of course also be deleted.

About my problem: I want to extend the example with the classes Showtime, Reservation and Movie. However, a reservation always refers to a concrete seat. I would pass a reference to a seat to the reservation:
[image]

In this case, can the composition between Room and Seat still remain or does it becomes an aggregation?

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: Why do you think it would change? I'm not sure about the other aggregations though. You probably want them to be regular associations.

Comment: From my understanding, a showtime is composed of a room and a movie. They do not form a physical unit but a logical one. I can also see the components of a showtime at the entrance of the cinema, where I can see the details of the showtime on a display. Likewise, a reservation is composed of a showtime and a seat. These elements can be seen on a ticket.

Comment: A shared aggregation has no defined semantics. You can place them where you want. But without giving the meaning in the context you simply confuse your readers.

Comment: As for the `Seat`. You probably keep the seat when you destroy the room, so can use it in another room. You probably should not use a composite aggregation here either.

Comment: I assume that with normal software for cinema owners, when you delete a room, you delete the seats. The seats form a part-whole relationship with their rooms. Maybe it's possible to expand the seats and put them in another room, but mapping that is not part of a software for cinema owners.

Comment: I as an owner would very much care for assets I have paid for,,,

Answer (score 1):

***Preliminary side remark**: for the sake of simplicity, you could remove all the shared aggregation (white diamonds), because UML doesn’t define their semantic and they do not fundamentaly change the meaning compared to ordinary associations.*

Let’s look at the **whole scenario** and keep the composite aggregaton. The consequence is the following:

- If you delete a room, the seat would die. This sounds logic, because the seat does not make any sense without the enclosing room.
- If you accept that a room gets deleted if still in use by a showtime, you accept that some showtimes may not be linked anymore to a room.
- In a similar manner, this may propagate to the reservation, since some reservations would loose their link to a seat.

Now is this scenario a problem? I routinely have a reservation for a flight without the reservation being linked to a seat. So it is up to you to decide how you want to handle it:

- You could constrain the deletion of the room to require that it is not linked to any showtime. You therefore avoid the described situation.
- You could accept any room deletion, if you decide to offer some reallocation functions that would allow to deal with showtime and reservations without room and seat (at least temporarily) and reassign a showtime and the reservation to a different room.

You may even go further and opt for a mixed scenario, and accept that deletion of the room is possible if no showtime exist in the future (active showtime) bust simply do not care for for reservations on past showtimes.

Comment: Thank you for your insightful contribution. However, I still wonder whether the relationship between Seat and Room still meets the definition of a composition if the third class Reservation has references to Seat.

Comment: @Z.J There is a strong difference between an ownership association and and an association without ownership. In the end it remains a designer’s choice. Here,  it is up to you to see if the seat has still a meaning without the room. Does seat 9C means something if you don’t know the related room 25? I mean from a semantic point of view (technically you could always use a surrogate key).  I’d even pretend that the room is part of the identity of the seat (independently of any keys you might chose).

Comment: This difference is so important that some languages  make distinction between a strong  and a weak link. Weak links do not prohibit deletion at the other end. (eg. [swift](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/AutomaticReferenceCounting.html) or [C++](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr))

Comment: @Z.J, do you need to preserve historical information? E.g. do you need to keep past reservations in your system, or will a reservation be deleted as soon as the showtime has ended? If you need past reservations, then you will probably also need to keep seats that existed in the past in your system. In that case, you never delete any object, but you set an 'end-date' or a 'deleted' property on past objects. On the other hand, if you delete reservations immediately when the showtime has ended, there is no problem with deletion of rooms and seats either.